# How to position a div in bottom right unless a certian point is reached

Tags: html, css

Hi this is an easy noob question but I have to ask it anyway. See my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jjalbert/xXdev/

code:

```
<h1>Hi!</h1>
<p>Some more text</p>
<div id="bottomcorner"></div>

#bottomcorner {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}    

h1 {
    color: green;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

p {
    color: blue;
    width: 230px;
}
```

I have an element fixed to the bottom right but I want it to remain in a static position once a certain browser width is created so that it doesn't start interfering with the content to the left of it.

So in my fiddle once the browser window is about 330px wide I would want the red box to stay in place and become unfixed from the corner of the browser.

Comment: i think you will need javascript for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could float it right and put it inside of a div with a max-width, then fix the div's position at the bottom instead of the red box to the bottom right.

Answer (score 2):

Check out CSS Media Queries. This should get the job done.

[CSS Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

```
@media all and (min-width: 300px) {
    ...css rules here...
}
```